# PHP : Simplexml parse node

Tags: php, simplexml

I have a php code that use to parse xml data, but it is not working, my php code look as following:

```
<?php
            $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <videos>
                    <video>
                        <id>751985</id>
                        <embed><![CDATA[somehtmlcode]]></embed>
                        <thumbs>
                            <thumb><![CDATA[http://example.com/images/thum01.jpg></thumb>
                            <thumb><![CDATA[http://example.com/images/thum02.jpg></thumb>
                            <thumb><![CDATA[http://example.com/images/thum03.jpg></thumb>
                            <thumb><![CDATA[http://example.com/images/thum04.jpg></thumb>
                            <thumb><![CDATA[http://example.com/images/thum05.jpg></thumb>
                            <thumb><![CDATA[http://example.com/images/thum06.jpg></thumb>
                            <thumb><![CDATA[http://example.com/images/thum07.jpg></thumb>
                            <thumb><![CDATA[http://example.com/images/thum08.jpg></thumb>
                        </thumbs>
                        <link><![CDATA[http://example.com/001]]></link>
                        <title><![CDATA[Some cool title 1]]></title>
                        <categories>
                            <category><![CDATA[Cat1]]></category>
                            <category><![CDATA[Cat2]]></category>
                            <category><![CDATA[Cat3]]></category>
                            <category><![CDATA[Cat4]]></category>
                        </categories>
                        <tags>
                            <tag><![CDATA[tag1]></tag>
                            <tag><![CDATA[tag2]></tag>
                            <tag><![CDATA[tag3]></tag>
                        </tags>
                        <someone>
                        </someone>
                        <duration><![CDATA[8:17]]></duration>
                        <pubDate><![CDATA[2014-05-14]]></pubDate>
                    </video>
                    <video>
                        <id>751988</id>
                        <embed><![CDATA[somehtmlcode]]></embed>
                        <thumbs>
                            <thumb><![CDATA[http://example.com/images/thum01.jpg></thumb>
                            <thumb><![CDATA[http://example.com/images/thum02.jpg></thumb>
                            <thumb><![CDATA[http://example.com/images/thum03.jpg></thumb>
                            <thumb><![CDATA[http://example.com/images/thum04.jpg></thumb>
                            <thumb><![CDATA[http://example.com/images/thum05.jpg></thumb>
                            <thumb><![CDATA[http://example.com/images/thum06.jpg></thumb>
                            <thumb><![CDATA[http://example.com/images/thum07.jpg></thumb>
                            <thumb><![CDATA[http://example.com/images/thum08.jpg></thumb>
                        </thumbs>
                        <link><![CDATA[http://example.com/001]]></link>
                        <title><![CDATA[Some cool title 1]]></title>
                        <categories>
                            <category><![CDATA[Cat1]]></category>
                            <category><![CDATA[Cat2]]></category>
                            <category><![CDATA[Cat3]]></category>
                            <category><![CDATA[Cat4]]></category>
                        </categories>
                        <tags>
                            <tag><![CDATA[tag1]></tag>
                            <tag><![CDATA[tag2]></tag>
                            <tag><![CDATA[tag3]></tag>
                        </tags>
                        <someone>
                        </someone>
                        <duration><![CDATA[8:17]]></duration>
                        <pubDate><![CDATA[2014-05-14]]></pubDate>
                    </video>
                </videos>';



        $sxe = simplexml_load_string($xml);     

        foreach ($sxe->video as $videoChild) {
        echo $videoChild->id; 
        echo $videoChild->title;


        }

?>
```

it does not get the value of node, i need to get id, embed, thumb, link, title, without the CDATA tag. any help would be great.

Comment: Does it echo `<![CDATA[somehtmlcode]]>` or nothing? Why even use the CDATA sections?

Comment: close your `<![CDATA[]]>` properly for `thumb` and `tag` tags. Must have `]]>` before closing xml tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <thumb><![CDATA[http://example.com/images/thum01.jpg></thumb>
```

the [CDATA] things aren't closed properly, simplexml_load_string() doesn't like that

try

```
 <thumb><![CDATA[http://example.com/images/thum01.jpg]]></thumb>
```

Comment: that work, but how to i do foreach inside a foreach to get the all thumb url?

Comment: currently i only can get first thumb url using:

foreach ($videoChild->thumbs as $thumbChild){
echo $thumbChild->thumb."\n"; 
}

Comment: no more answer? i need loop into thumbs to get thumb